# Vim eats all my lines if I map ddkP

Tags: vim, keymapping

In Vim, I set a mapping to move a line up with each press of `_`

`nnoremap _ ddkP`

In my experiments, when I reach the top of my Vim file, all the lines get eaten up if I continue to press and hold `_`

Is something wrong? I'm on the Mac, but using the console Vim, not MacVim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kristo's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163672/78845) looks logical to me.

I suggest that you try this mapping instead, which does a [`:move`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:move) without deleting any lines:

```
:nnoremap _ :move .-2<CR>
```

You can also undo this atomically.

Answer (score 3):

The `k` (move up one line) fails when at the top of a file.  I suspect this causes the mapped keys execution to stop, leaving you with just `dd` (delete current line).  To fix this, you'll need a [less destructive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163607/46821) way to move the line.